# why my sql statement, inserts two rows in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following code, knowing that its not in a loop. although i'm requiring it in another file but still its not in a loop.
I don't know why i'm getting two rows in the database after executing those lines

```
 $stmt400 = $db->prepare("insert into history (last_scan,warning_files,new_files,username) values(?,?,?,?)");
$stmt400->execute(array($date,$sum,$row100[0],$user));
```

Comment: Well I dont think its these 2 statements on there own that is causing 2 rows to be inserted

Comment: Delete both rows in database, commit, and then run your code again to confirm the same.

Comment: Not enough information here. Please show us more REAL code

Comment: Use [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) to see, why it's executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're requiring the file twice, you can use `require_once` to prevent it from loading and executing anything twice.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is required in another file then it will execute and lead to two insertions.
I suggest you put the code in a function in the file you require.
That way it will not execute automatically and will only be called when you call that function.

Comment: I dont see why those 2 lines in a file that is `required` would run the 2 lines more than once unless it is being required more than once in the main script

Comment: @alkoofi writes that the code is **also in the file** that is being required .
So that makes the code to run twice

Comment: I was imagining that that was a linguistic error by someone whos not a native English speaker

Comment: this is not the only code in the file that is required. But still its not a loop or any thing that will lead to run those lines more than once. plus i tried not to require it and copy it in the original file, still the same problem